# order sub categories alphabetically

Tags: category-tree

I have spent hours searching forums and trying several methods but cant get anywhere. does anyone know how to order all sub categories in magento to display alphabetically front end A-Z?

Comment: in layered navigation ?

Comment: yes, layered navigation

Answer (score 3):

if you take a look on the template file for layered navigation (`catalog\layer\view.phtml`), you can see that, layered navigation filtering is carried out by this call

```
<?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
```

So take a look on `getFilters()` method in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` block class.

```
public function getFilters()
{
    $filters = array();
    if ($categoryFilter = $this->_getCategoryFilter()) {
        $filters[] = $categoryFilter;
    }

    $filterableAttributes = $this->_getFilterableAttributes();
    foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
        $filters[] = $this->getChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter');
    }

    return $filters;
}
```

Here you can see that, the method returns an array `$filters`, which is get filled in two sections. First the array get filled by category filters then it is filled by custom attribute filters. **This means that, category filters are available in layered navigation by default**

If we dig more and more, we will reach in the model class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category`, where the actual category filters for layered navigations are carried out. The method that we interested here is `_getItemsData()`

```
 protected function _getItemsData()
{
    $key = $this->getLayer()->getStateKey().'_SUBCATEGORIES';
    $data = $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->getCacheData($key);

    if ($data === null) {
        $categoty   = $this->getCategory();
        /** @var $categoty Mage_Catalog_Model_Categeory */
        $categories = $categoty->getChildrenCategories();

        $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()
            ->addCountToCategories($categories);

        $data = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category->getIsActive() && $category->getProductCount()) {
                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($category->getName()),
                    'value' => $category->getId(),
                    'count' => $category->getProductCount(),
                );
            }
        }
        $tags = $this->getLayer()->getStateTags();
        $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->saveCacheData($data, $key, $tags);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This is where category filters are preparing. The heart of this function is `foreach`. It uses that loop to load the `$data` variable(holds an array) which is then return to layered navigation filter. You can again see that, `$data` holds only 3 parameter of a specific category. They are `label`,`value` and `children count`. So the category section that present in layered navigation actually built up with these three values.

So this is the place that we need to work. By default categories are loading in random, means no filtering is applying there. What we need to do is, we need to sort the `$data` variable in ascending order.

So rewrite this model as like this.

```
 protected function _getItemsData()
{
    $key = $this->getLayer()->getStateKey().'_SUBCATEGORIES';
    $data = $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->getCacheData($key);

    if ($data === null) {
        $categoty   = $this->getCategory();
        /** @var $categoty Mage_Catalog_Model_Categeory */
        $categories = $categoty->getChildrenCategories();

        $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()
            ->addCountToCategories($categories);

        $data = array();

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category->getIsActive() && $category->getProductCount()) {
                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($category->getName()),
                    'value' => $category->getId(),
                    'count' => $category->getProductCount(),
                );
            }
        }

        function cmp($a, $b)
        {
            return strcmp($a["label"], $b["label"]);
        }
        usort($data, "cmp");
        $tags = $this->getLayer()->getStateTags();
        $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->saveCacheData($data, $key, $tags);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This is the additional part that do the job for us

```
        function cmp($a, $b)
        {
            return strcmp($a["label"], $b["label"]);
        }
        usort($data, "cmp");
```

This will filter categories in ascending order for layered navigation.

**Note::** You are lucky, I have this in extension format. You can use it. **[This is the github page that holds that extension](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/sort-layered-navigation-category)**. Feel free to use it

Comment: hi many thanks for taking your time to get back to me. I downloaded your extension and uploaded the files to my ftp but navigation still isnt ordering sub categories a-z - is there something else i need to do? thanks

Comment: magento version ?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Comment: no way.. I have checked. It is working for me. are you sure you put my extension correctly and please note the extension sort category part of layered navigation, not any other part

Comment: hi yeah i just placed full app directory to my website and cleared cache but still not sorting a-z in layered nav.. perhaps because i have custom theme?

Comment: custom theme is not a problem. because extension do not have theme related stuff. Ok check whether extesnsion is enabled or not through admin side

Comment: hi sorry but where do I check that in admin?

Comment: go to `system > configuration > advanced`. there you can see a heading. click on that. It will show some data. It is the list of modules that are using in magento. Check for `Programmerrkt_Layerednav` which is enabled or not

Comment: hi yes just checked and your extension is set to enabled?

Comment: is that set to enabled ?

Comment: yes.. not sure what to check now?

Comment: is it showing enabled along with the name ?

Comment: yes, correct - it is showing enable

Comment: then why its not working. Ok then do this care fully. Make my extension disabled. Select disable from dropdown and save. It will disable my module. Now you need to copy the file in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Cateogory.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Cateogory.php`.(note it need to paste in `app/code/local` by keeping the same path). Then copy the code that I provided in my answer. ie `_getItemsData()`. Replace existing `_getItemsData()`  with that one. Check the output then.

Comment: if you have any doubt on the process ask me

Comment: thanks but i dont have this directory app/code/local/Mage/ - there is no "Mage" in app/code/local. There is instead a folder called "Meigee" which then brings you into a folder called "CategoriesEnhanced" ?

Comment: yes you need to create all those folders. Exact same path

Comment: please ensure all  first letters are capital letter(from Mage). Do not miss that. Its very important

Comment: ah okay thanks - i have created these folders. but now i am unsure what file to edit when you mention: Then copy the code that I provided in my answer. ie _getItemsData(). Replace existing _getItemsData() with that one

Comment: open that `Category.php` file. You will see that method. What you need to do is, delete that function. Then replace with mine. Note the second one in the answer. First one is exactly same as that present in that file. Means instead of the default one that present in that file, you need to use mine. Dont touch anyother part.Just that function

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I have Category.php in /public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter with your code above and have cleared cache but sub cats still not ordering a-z? :(

Comment: it should work. i am damn sure about it. That means any of your custom extension not allowing to do that.

Comment: so this is the last thing you can try. enable my extension through admn. And disable each module that do not start with `Mage`. First try to disabele `Meigee_CategoriesEnhanced`. Then save. Reload the page again. Repeat this step for all other extensions available there. If you are lucky, it will work

Comment: hi i tried disabling all other modules and keepings yours enabled, but sub categories still did not list a-z. will just have to do it manually. thank you kindly for your time